# Find custom 'divider' > Wrap each side accordingly

Tags: jquery, markers

I'm looking for a way to target a specific marker in a document, like for instance `!divide!` or `--divide--` Something that doesnt normally exist in language written by *normal* humanbeings yet something that doesnt take a rocket scientist to conjure and yet again one that *is distinct from regular text*.

Then target that `!divide!` and wrap text while removing `!divided!`. Like this:

`Lorem ipsum dolor !divide! sit amet` becomes >>

`<p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p> <p>sit amet</p>`

And

`Lorem !divide! ipsum dolor !divide! sit amet` becomes >>

`<p>Lorem</p> <p>ipsum dolor</p> <p>sit amet</p>`

This is.. Well, this is what i have so far. More than anything, it's me trying to get my thoughts together and try to tell what im looking for here: http://jsfiddle.net/PvMJL/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will avoid issues if you have nested `.TextCont` elements. If that won't happen, you can get rid of the [`not()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method.

```
var with_dividers = $('.TextCont:contains("--divider--")')
               .not('> .TextCont:contains("--divider--")');


with_dividers.html(function(i,htm) {
    return '<p>' + htm.split('--divider--').join('</p><p>') + '</p>';
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/CFLV4/

And I changed your IDs to classes since duplicate IDs are invalid.

---

**Edit:** To explain, in JavaScript, you don't append opening and closing tags. You need to think in terms of dealing with *whole elements*.

In the code above, the [`html()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method is passed a function. The return value of the function is the *new content* of the element. The `htm` parameter is passed a String of the *current content*.

So what we do is take the existing content, and do a `.split('--divider--')`, resulting in an Array, like:

```
['<span>Lorem</span>',
  '<a href="#">ipsum</a>',
  'dolor sit amet.'
]
```

As you can see, the `--divider--` text has been removed, and the string split where the `--divider--` was.

Then we do a `.join()` on the Array, using `'</p><p>'` as the join text, giving us:

```
'<span>Lorem</span></p><p><a href="#">ipsum</a></p><p>dolor sit amet.'
```

...but of course we're missing our opening and closing tags, so we add those to the beginning and end, so our code:

```
'<p>' + htm.split('--divider--').join('</p><p>') + '</p>'
```

...ultimately gives us:

```
'<p><span>Lorem</span></p><p><a href="#">ipsum</a></p><p>dolor sit amet.</p>'
```

That is the return value of the function, and therefore becomes the new content.

Comment: Could you explain to me kinda how this works.. as i hit into couple walls that i had thought of in my original idea but kinda forgot to mention about it when i posted. You see, I would still like to offer chance to add html tags inside the element that holds `--divider--`'s. http://jsfiddle.net/CFLV4/1/ As you can see, they kinda break the paragraphs.

Comment: @Lollero: The reason it's breaking is that the browser will not allow an `<h1>` to be inside a `<p>` since it's invalid HTML. You'd have the same issue if that was the original HTML, unaffected by JavaScript. [Change it to a `<span>`](http://jsfiddle.net/CFLV4/2/) and it works.

Comment: Right, right.. Of course. This is getting more complicated as i keep missing things. I know how i could kinda get past that but it would kinda defeat the purpose cause i would have to add more stuff like `--start--` which would be right after `h1` or something like that..

Comment: @Lollero: So you're saying you want to keep elements like the `<h1>` (and any others) *out* tags out of the `<p>` wrappers? If so, that's very doable. BTW, I added more explanation to my answer.

Comment: Idk.. I mean in ideal world i would, but the more i think about it.. the more elements would have to be taken into account.. To ignore `ul, ol, h1, h2..` and so on.

Comment: @Lollero: Yeah, to include only valid (inline) ones, that would get a bit complicated.

Comment: Hey, would it make sense to end the <p> on on every element it encounters somehow and then ignore that behavior on <a> and <span>. Idk.. i think i might just have to get back to the drawingboard..

Comment: @Lollero: It would take something like getting all the contents of each element, filtering through them, grouping adjacent textNodes and/or inline elements together, and wrapping those adjacent groups. So it could be done something like that.

Comment: Well, thanks its been a big help. Especially that explanation on how it works.

Comment: @patrickdw let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2257/discussion-between-lollero-and-patrick-dw)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var textToSearch = "!divide!"
$('containerSelector:contains("'+ textToSearch +'")').each(function(){
   $(this).html("<p>" + $(this).text().replace(textToSearch, "</p> <p>") + "</p>");
});
```